# Linked List inserting trouble

Tags: c, coding-style, singly-linked-list

I am having trouble with inserting items in linked list. All the elements end up having the same *data content that is inserted in the last. The program compiles successfully. I use gcc and gdb.
I am new to coding so please mention troubles if any that you see in my programming style.

```
typedef struct Node{
    void* data;
    struct Node* next;
} *node;

node allocate(){
    node current = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    current->data = NULL;
    current->next = NULL;
    return current;
}


void insert(node *head, void *data){
    // if head has no data then set the data on head and return
    if(((*head)->data == NULL)&&((*head)->next == NULL)){
        (*head)->data = data;
        return;
    }

    node newHead = allocate();
    newHead->data = data;
    newHead->next = *head;
    *head = newHead;
    //printf("Node Data : %d\tNext Node Data : %d",
        //*(int *)((*head)->data), *(int *)((*head)->data));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    node head = allocate();
    int count = inputSequence(&head);
    int *aod = calloc((size_t) count, sizeof(int));
    generateAOD(head, aod);
    if(checkJolly(aod, count) == TRUE)
        printf("Jolly\n");
    else
        printf("Not Jolly\n");

    return 0;
}

int inputSequence(node *input){
    int *num = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int count = 0;

    while((scanf("%d", num) != EOF)){
        insert(input, (void *)num);
        count++;
    }
    traverse(*input, fn);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code of the `main` function?

Comment: yes.
I have placed the main function and the linklist module actually in different files

Comment: @lc2817         ..
Can I upload files on stackoverflow or maybe I can email them?

Comment: One problem I see right off the top, you're using a pre-allocated head pointer with the `data` member state being non-null in determining if the list is "empty". There is absolutely no reason for that. The head pointer *itself* (null vs. not-null) is a much cleaner indicator of "empty" state. Second. You never allocate a new node in your `insert()` function, so of course there is no "insertion" happening.

Comment: Add the file with the main below your other code. Thanks

Comment: @lc2817 I am not stupidly not aware of how to add the file

Comment: @WhozCraig I have actually done the allocation using the allocate function.

Comment: node allocate(){
     node current = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
     current->data = NULL;
     current->next = NULL;
     return current;
    }

Comment: @user2794538: I was confused by your usage of the word `upload`, I didn't know that you meant `paste`, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert logic is non-existant. And you're literally making your life harder by attempting to manage a linked list in the fashion you're using.

The head pointer itself should indicate whether the list is empty. If it is NULL, its empty. If it isn't, there's data. Code the insertion logic accordingly.

And your `inputSequence` is utterly broken. It only allocates ONE data point, then uses the same data allocation for *every* insertion. You need one for *each* insertion.

First, change `allocate()` to accept the data being inserted. It will make the remaining code less cluttered:

```
node allocate(void *data)
{
    node current = malloc(sizeof(*current));
    current->data = data;
    current->next = NULL;
    return current;
}
```

Second, insert by allocating a new node as needed.

```
void insert(node *head, void *data)
{
    node p = allocate(data);
    p->next = *head;
    *head = p;
}
```

Next, fix `inputSequence()` to properly allocate memory for each entry:

```
int inputSequence(node *input)
{
    int count = 0;
    int num = 0;

    // note: check for number of params *successfully* parsed.
    //  if it isn't 1, its time to leave the loop.
    while(scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
    {
        int *data = malloc(sizeof(num));
        *data = num;
        insert(input, data);
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

And lastly, make sure your head pointer is initially NULL in `main()`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node head = NULL;

    // load linked list
    inputSequence(&head);

    // ... the rest of your code....;

    return 0;
}
```

With the above, the logical answer of "Is my list empty" is simply `if (!head)` Further, this makes things like traversal trivial.

```
void traverse(node ptr, void (*pfn)(void *))
{
    while (ptr)
    {
        pfn(ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Freeing the list is equally trivial:

```
void destroy(node *head)
{
    while (*head)
    {
        node p = *head;
        *head = p->next;
        free(p->data);
        free(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2794538 No problem. I just hope it made sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
   typedef struct Node{
         void* data; // Make it as int or any other data type
         struct Node* next;
   } *node;
```

In function inputSequence() you are allocating memory for num at the very beginning and making node->data point to this memory each time you are adding a node. Hence data pointer of each node of your linked list points to the same memory location and hence contains the same value.

If you still want to continue with data as a void pointer, allocate num for each iteration of the while loop and pass this to insert function.

```
    while((scanf("%d", num) != EOF)){
        num = malloc(sizeof(int);
        insert(input, (void *)num);
        count++;
    }
```